# Decode ascii and reversed words sentence

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

In a challenge of CodingGame, there is a challenge that ask you to decode a string composed by reversed words ('Hello world' > 'olleH dlrow') then each characters converted into ascii value separeted by space:

```
>>> decode('111 108 108 101 72 32 100 108 114 111 119 32 41 58')
Hello world :)
```

The challenge is to be the fastest to write the `decode` function, but I later tried to write it with the fewest character possible.

Here is my result (104 characters):

```
def decode(m,s=' '):return s.join([w[::-1]for w in(''.join([chr(int(c))for c in m.split(s)]).split(s))])
```

The name of the function doesn't matter, it can be shorter, but only rename variable isn't good enough for an answer.

Is it possible to improve this result ?

Comment: Does the function have to be called `decode`? Is a specific version required? Can the output contain whitespace that isn't spaces, and if so, how should it be handled?

Comment: This part is obviously longer than a 'd' or something else, and does not required any knowledge, so I don't care (the "Take input from STDIN and output to STDOUT" part of the Jo King answer is pertinent). It must contain the ascii character '32'.

Comment: To clarify, is this challenge limited to only Python?  Also is I/O restricted to a function that takes as input an ASCII space character delimited string?  Not [Default I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)?

Comment: This challenge is ok for default I/O method, but I'm new to this SE, sorry. I will edit the questions since all answer provide the default solution too. And thanks for the link about "default I/O methods!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 75 bytes

```python
lambda a:' '.join(''.join(map(chr,map(int,a.split())))[::-1].split()[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzRCoMwDEV/JW@t4MSoY1rYl2x7yKxgh7bB1Qe/vqvWBcJNDifhzY/O1kEPvdMD3OEZJprfmoCUAFF8nLFSnDkTy35c8j2N9TkVX56Ml1msh1IXfP1B2rLAS/Rkeh5PeD3kgIiAZXs2wq2CuopTmQg2cBjY7bhBuLY/)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 70 bytes

If taking input from STDIN and outputing to STDOUT is fine then it takes only 70 bytes this is mostly because the spread operator (`*`) is shorter than `' '.join()`

```python
print(*''.join(map(chr,map(int,input().split())))[::-1].split()[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ0tdXS8rPzNPIzexQCM5o0gHRAMldDLzCkpLNDT1igtyMoE0EERbWekaxsIEIDzN//8NDQ0VDA0soNhQwdxIwdgIyDKAiBiaKIBVGFqChE0MFUwtAA)

Comment: Your solution in 70 bytes works, also, for your lambda in 75 is good too.

Answer (score 6):

#### Use lambdas

```
def f(a,b):return c
```

can be shortened to

```
f=lambda a,b:c
```

(the `f=` can also be removed per CGCC site standards)

#### Remove excess `[]`s

```
x.join([a for b in c])
```

can be

```
x.join(a for b in c)
```

since join can take a generator instead of a list

#### Split is on spaces by default

*Thanks ElPedro for reminding me about this*

So the `split(' ')`s can be shortened, which in turn means the `s=' '` doesn't help (and it only broke even in the first place).

#### Take input from STDIN and output to STDOUT

`print` will automatically print arguments with space as a separator if you use `*` to [unpacks the sequence/collection into positional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/6251742), and taking input via `input()` is shorter. Also, setting `s` to space doesn't actually save any bytes.

Altogether, this is 79 bytes:

```python
print(*[w[::-1]for w in(''.join(chr(int(c))for c in input().split()).split())])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYpbCoQwFEO3cv9sBcX4QMetiF8FsSJtqR3E1dfbcUBIyCGJu8JqTROj89oEkU/nNI4F5sV6OkkbkWXlZjnV6kV6KCnTpnhjuW8QsjzcrjlfmGWMAAjV8Deor6mpmaqnQUu/Bz6pbkHdcAM)

or, if you're dedicated to having a function, 82 bytes:

```python
lambda m:' '.join(w[::-1]for w in(''.join(chr(int(c))for c in m.split()).split()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NDoIwEIRfZW5tDxIWMCIJT6IesMVQQ3@CNcSnr60QD5PMfDOb9Z8wOVtHNUqnRvS4xnkwdzXAdAyseDpt@XrpugPdHm7BipTZzuW0cG0Dl0LkTqYOpnj5WQcuxN@I6Jc8236kC//eMBGBynYX4VShrpIrN0INfgs6Z9wQju0X)

plus seven or so characters if you really need the function to be called `decode`

Comment: Python splits on space by default so you can lose another 6 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NDoIwEIRfZW5tDxIWMCIJT6IesMVQQ3@CNcSnr60QD5PMfDOb9Z8wOVtHNUqnRvS4xnkwdzXAdAyseDpt@XrpugPdHm7BipTZzuW0cG0Dl0LkTqYOpnj5WQcuxN@I6Jc8236kC//eMBGBynYX4VShrpIrN0INfgs6Z9wQju0X "Python 3 – Try It Online") :)

Comment: The actual challenge works with `input()` and `print()`, so in fact, this problem can be solved in 79 bytes on CodingGame.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 78 bytes

```python
lambda m:' '.join(x[::-1]for x in''.join(map(chr,map(int,m.split()))).split())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYrbCsIwGINfJeymFebYXyfOgk@iXlSlrLIeqBXm09duDgMh4UvCJw3eiaxxwiWPyt4eClYysObpjePTWcotXbWPmGAcW7FVgd@HWM9pXKpt8wqjSXxT9K85xLJxXR7hvWy5IiJQ268mHAR2orT2R6jD8qDjjDvCvq@@)

**Edit** changed to a Python 2 answer as the `lambda` is shorter than the `print`/`input` version in Python 2.

This uses a couple of `map`s to get the list of characters which we then `join` on "", `split` again on space, reverse each element then re`join` again on space for 78. Also works in Python 3.

Just a pity that it needs so many brackets :-(

Comment: and 75 with print and input: `print(*[x[::-1]for x in''.join(map(chr,map(int,input().split()))).split()])`

Comment: I missed that as I am more familiar with Python 2 in which the `print` and `input` version comes out at 79 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EXV0vKz8zT6Mi2spK1zA2Lb9IoUIhMw8mnJtYoJGcUaQDooGqdTLzCkpLNDT1igtyMoE0EMCZ//8rGRoaKhgaWECxoYK5kYKxEZBlABExNFEAqzC0BAmbGCqYWigBAA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: 80 in fact as I had missed out the space [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYrRCoJAFER/5eLLbmDirEbmr0QPIYQ36u5l3cC@fltNHBjmcBj9xtGLS0kDSzRkqqdnsfO174@4PXygmVjMpt93tcMYymXzvWTRT7SHatIX583ZMaUCAKHutoLOjhqXqf4btLQ@cFl0Czp1xQ8 "Python 2 – Try It Online")